# Floor, ceil problem

Tags: integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, pi

Edit-For what values of $k$, -$2$+ $\left\lceil\frac{(6k+1)\pi }{6}\right\rceil=\left\lfloor\frac{(6k-1) \pi}{6}\right\rfloor$ where $k$ is positive integer greater than equal to one?

Comment: Please, in the future, typeset your questions using MathJax.

Comment: What have you tried?  What does the fractional part of $6k\pi$ have to be to make this true?

Comment: @RossMillikan[link](https://mathoverflow.net/q/24579)

Comment: @DevanshSingh:  what does that link have to do with this problem?

Comment: I find it is false only for $39, 46, 53, 60,67,74, 152,159,166,173,180,187,265,272,279,286,293,300,378,385,392,399,406,413491,498,505,512,519,526$ up to $600$.  So far, they come in blocks of $6$ at spacing of $7$ with blocks spaced by $113$.  The values $7,113$ recall the denominators of $\frac {22}7, \frac {355}{113}$

Comment: I was checking whether theta or x=pi/$6$ in (pi (k-1) +x, pi k-x) contains at least 2 integers which every x less than $1$/$2$ will satisfy and ]pi k-x, pi k+x[ contains only 1 integer so that we can divide infinite intervals of the integral in link which converge separately and intervals which may diverge. Sadly x=pi/$6$ fails at k=$39$, $46$.

Comment: The next convergent to $\pi$ has denominator $33102$ so I think you will have to look about that far to break the pattern I found.

Comment: Is there any theta or x less than pi/$6$ such that ]pi k-x, pi k+x[ contains no integer or I will call number of integers in this interval, y then for y=$0$, I came with inequality using floor, ceil function concepts and this condition that gives us upper bound of x but no lower bound of x which works only up to some k, for y=$0$, this works only up to k=$7$.For y=2 we get upper bound of x only up to k=22.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106954/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-devansh-singh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is **wrong**. When $k=39$ we have
$$\left\lceil{(6k-1)\pi\over6}\right\rceil=\lceil 121.9985\rceil=122,\qquad \left\lfloor{(6k+1)\pi\over6}\right\rfloor=\lfloor 123.0457\rfloor=123\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

You should convince yourself that you are looking for precisely the $k$ s.t. $\left(\frac{(6k-1)\pi}{6}, \frac{(6k+1)\pi}{6}\right) \cap \mathbb{Z} \neq \emptyset$. Then this happens iff $((6k-1) \pi, (6k+1)\pi) \cap 6\mathbb{Z} \neq \emptyset$.